# Is "Why Steven Sinofsky is out at Microsoft" correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

The title of [this *Ars Technica* piece](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/11/why-steven-sinofsky-is-out-at-microsoft/) reads:

> Why Steven Sinofsky is out at Microsoft

Concretely, I'm wondering why (if) "out at" is correct – I initially thought "out of" would be the correct option.

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/11/why-steven-sinofsky-is-out-at-microsoft/

Comment: It's fine at is. Think of "is out" as being roughly the same as "was fired" – so, it's another way to say: "Why Sinofsky was fired at Microsoft". "Was fired" refers to the _action_ (what happened _to_ Sinofsky), "is out" refers to the _state_ (i.e. the state of Sinofsky's employment status at the company). It's simply two ways to say essentially the same thing.

Comment: The phrase "out at" is also common in baseball, by the way: "Rodriguez is out at first."

Comment: @J.R. Your answer makes sense, why not make it an answer so I can accept it? I was indeed parsing the sentence "Why X is | out at | Microsoft" instead of the more likely "Why X | is out | at Microsoft"

Comment: I view this a bit differently.  When using "out of" the two words go together, but in the use of "out at" the two words are simply next to each other.  The pertinent phrases are "Steve is out" and "at Microsoft".  Similar to the way things can be "in"- Ironman is *in*, *The Shadow* is out, Steven Sinofsky is out.  Where is he out? At Microsoft.   This is different than *Steve is out of Microsoft*.  Along the lines of  "I'm out of here"- meaning I'm leaving.

Comment: @Jim: Precisely. Both "out" and "in" can have different meanings, which might be interesting to explore, but isn't what OP's asking about. He just wants us to "vote" on whether we find his **stylistic** choice better than the alternative. So it's Not Constructive.

Comment: Although bizarrely there is a possible distinction even there. Steve could be "out of favour" **at** MS, but still there (not actually *sacked*). On the other hand, if he was out **of** MS, he couldn't possibly be still there.

Comment: For those who have voted it to be "Not a Real Question", please state what is "difficult to tell about what is being asked here". This is an interesting question. +1

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In this case, an answer should show why the asker's assertion is wrong - by explaining how "out at" is correct, not just from grammar standpoint but with meaning in this sentence. Personally, I found the sentence bizarre - I'd understand "out of", but in this context I just don't get the meaning of "out". In other words, a question "is *X* correct? Isn't *Y* what should be used instead?" should be answered with "*X* is correct (and means...)" and not closed as not a real question or nonconstructive!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe the word "correct" in the question is a HUGE clue about what I'm talking about, which is precisely NOT style. When I saw "out at Microsoft" in the title of the article, I honestly thought it was a mistake. Given Jim's and J.R.'s explanations I can now parse it correctly. It still reads wrong to my eyes, but I can understand it.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic: All the word "correct" tells me is that you think it's at least possible one preposition is *right* and by implication, the other is *wrong*). That's simply not the case in your specific context, where either is acceptable (assuming one accepts the "journalese" style of the whole sentence in the first place). Individuals may have subjective opinions, but in practice both forms are used by many perfectly competent speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly! And that was the question. Now I know both are correct. Before asking the question I thought one was wrong. How on earth that makes the question non constructive?

Comment: @Vinko: The question text has changed a bit since the original, at which time it seemed to me you were firmly of the opinion that only "out **of**" would be "grammatically valid", and you sought confirmation of that from us. Firstly, you never explained *why* you don't like "out **at**" - which notwithstanding any comments here, seems perfectly "normal" to me. Secondly, it's a "journalese" *headline*, in which context the standard rules of grammar are somewhat irrelevant...

Comment: ... *and* (there may be a US/UK divide on this one) I believe that UK newspapers & magazines would be far more likely to use *"out **at**"*. There's no particular reason why this should be so, but to an extent, headlines do have their own grammar/stylistic conventions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've said it yourself, one is correct and, by implication, the other is wrong, so that's why I didn't like it, because I thought it was wrong! (FWIW, correct has been there with its implication from the first writing of the question.) Now, it's clear the question was too terse and I should have expanded it more. It just didn't occur to me that it was that ambiguous. If I had been talking about stylistic choices knowing both alternatives were correct, I'd have asked about which one is better, not if one version is correct.

Comment: @Vinko: I'm not aware I ever said *"one is correct and, by implication, the other is wrong"* (but if I did, I strongly disagree with myself! :) What I think is that analysing "journalese" syntax might be interesting in and of itself, but (to the extent that it observes standard or its own rules of grammar at all) it shouldn't be taken as indicative of normal language use in other contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You did it right here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91162/is-why-steven-sinofsky-is-out-at-microsoft-correct#comment182796_91162 Anyway, I believe we have made ourselves clear enough now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the use of *out at* in this sense is odd and a tad ambiguous. I suspect that it might be peculiar to American English.

> Why Steven Sinofsky is **out at Microsoft**

If I had not already been aware of Sinofsky leaving Microsoft, I might have interpreted the above headline as:

> Why Steven Sinofsky is **over at Microsoft**

In other words, it sounds as if Sinofsky is *over there* at Microsoft to do something.

The following are random examples from Google books where *out at X* is being used similar to *over at X*:

> My husband is as nervous over it as I am, but he is **out at his work** all day, while I get no rest from it.
>
> "The chief is **out at the fire**," the dispatcher told him.
>
> Your assistant, Peter, is **out at lunch**. Leave a message for him, explain what has happened and ask him to cancel your afternoon appointments.
>
> Perhaps it is a naive view and in the summer everybody is **out at the pub**, or simply, as I read is a growing tendency, just browned off with the box.

The following are random examples from Google Books where *out at X* is being used in the same sense as *out of X*:

> Republican Osberger is **out at Arthur Young**.
>
> PD/afternoon jock Tom Bradley is **out at WKKX** St. Louis. Operations director Russ Schell assumes his PD duties and is accepting T&Rs for the afternoon slot.

There appear to be fewer examples of this sort (which doesn't really say much) and all seem American as well. Perhaps it's a *baseball* reference?

I agree with the OP that "Why Steven Sinofsky is out **of** Microsoft" would have been a far clearer choice of headline.

Comment: I don't agree that _out of_ is "far clearer" – it, too, is subject to misinterpretation. (Sinofsky could be an investor, and he could be "out of Microsoft stock", for example). That aside, I agree with the thrust of your answer, that adjacent prepositions can have different meanings in different contexts. I think the real lesson is, when reading adjacent prepositions in a newspaper headline, sometimes you'll have to read the article to disambiguate possible interpretations.

Comment: @J.R. Everything is subject to misinterpretation and perspective. However, from where I am sitting and in my general experience, "He is out of Microsoft" is far more representative of a _firing_ than "He is out at Microsoft". While you are quite right that one ought to read the entire article, the whole point of headlines is to provide an in-a-nutshell summary of it; if it does not do this, then it is simply a bad headline. With that said, _out at_ might be perfectly understood by an American audience.

Comment: Given that it's a headline, it can't mean "He's out visiting Microsoft". I would understand that "out of" indicates a voluntary departure ("I'm out of here!") and "out at" indicates sacking. He was at Microsoft; and now he's out.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Why **can't** it mean that? The reader might not know who Sinofsky is. He might be a famous scientist or a "fixer-upper" or a comedian going over there to boost flagging morale. What he's going to do at Microsoft might or might not be implicitly understood. To me, "Why the police are out at Microsoft" means that the article is about the police "visiting" Microsoft and not leaving it. When you're _out at work_, you're not necessarily _visiting_ work. You are going to work to do your job which is implicit in the statement.

Comment: @coleopterist: If he was there as a consulting temp, I think the headline would simply read: **Sinofsky at Microsoft**. It's likely that a headline writer would simply forgo the "out", if merely wanting to communicate that Sinofsky was *there*.

Comment: @J.R. I cannot know what the headline writer wants or does not want to communicate. When "out at X" can mean "visiting X" (as demonstrated by my provided examples), then its use to also mean "leaving X" or "fired from X" is ambiguous. The OP appears to have been disconcerted and I can understand why.

Comment: Let's not debate this too much. Headline writers have the unenviable task of scrunching an in-depth summary into a very few words using an ambiguous language, leading to many possible interpretations, some of them rather amusing (just try Googling "funny newspaper headlines"). Heck, Sinofsky could be admitting he's a homosexual, and the headline "Sinofsky is out at Microsoft" would work (see [Meaning 37](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/out)). Sinofsky could also be a computer (like Watson at IBM) that crashed – guess what? _Sinofsky is out at Microsoft_ works again.

Comment: J.R.: Or Sinofsky could be the codename for a super-duper new networking technology being introduced at MS's HQ, in which case it could be "down". In that scenario, "out" could be used for exactly the same meaning. (I'm not sure what it would mean if *"Sinofsky was down **and** out at Microsoft"* - would he be living on skid row because MS don't pay enough? :)